# Android ListView (not ListActivity) connecting to SQLite DB using CustomCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I am trying to create Custom Cursor adapter and attach it to my listview.

Though I am not yet there to create textboxes and set values inside my adapter,
 my code currently throws a runtime exception when I try to call super(ctx, c);

What could be wrong? Searched all over the web & couldn't get it. Thanks in advance!

Custom Cursor adapter:

```
public class CustomCursorAdaptor extends CursorAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;

    public CustomCursorAdaptor (Context ctx, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(ctx,  c);
        this.context = ctx;
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return(new View(context));
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

        }
}
```

and my Activity:

```
public class DynamicScrollView extends Activity {
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Context ctx=getBaseContext();
        RelativeLayout newLayout=new RelativeLayout(ctx);
        ListView lv=new ListView(ctx);

    SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase("TShow.db", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);

        Cursor cur = db.query("control", new String[] {"id"}, "parent_id=2", null, null, null, null);

        CustomCursorAdaptor adapter = new CustomCursorAdaptor(ctx, lv.getId(), cur, new String[] {"id"}, new int[] {2});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

         newLayout.addView(lv);
         setContentView(newLayout);
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursor adapter expects to have a column _id which it uses as index. I added another column as _id in the select and it worked! Updated code:

```
Cursor cur = db.query("control", new String[] {"id as _id", "id"}, "parent_id=2", null, null, null, null);
```

I traced it back from the exception description which said: column '_id' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know much about the base context, which you are passing to your `CursorAdaptor` here, but I understand that usually you should rather be using your `Activity` as the context. `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`, in case you did not know.

So, in stead of:

```
new CustomCursorAdaptor(ctx, lv.getId(), cur, new String[] {"id"}, new int[] {2});
```

... you could try:

```
new CustomCursorAdaptor(this, lv.getId(), cur, new String[] {"id"}, new int[] {2});
```

Comment: I found out what the problem is. It was not the context. Cursor adapter expects to have a column _id which it uses as index. I added another column as _id in the select and it worked! Updated code: `code` Cursor cur = db.query("control", new String[] {"id as _id", "id"}, "parent_id=2", null, null, null, null);
 `code`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the golden tip about the _id column which is needed for the ListView to work.

@dmg: you must not name your _id column with the (native)SQL 'AS' statement. Just add the '_id' column without changing it.